# How to build a 3d diamond in openframeworks for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, 3d, openframeworks, cinder

How to build a 3d diamond in openframeworks for iOS? I'm having a hard time finding useful tutorials for 3d rendering in openframeworks, and I am coming from Processing.

Comment: do you mean building the actual geometry or rendering a realistic diamond ?

Comment: I mean building the geometry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two sides of the story:

1. the nerdy openframeworks/c++/gl part part: how do you actually render a mesh of triangles together
2. the fun part: geometry

For the 1st part I recommend starting with the oF documentation on [ofVbo](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/gl/ofVbo.html).
The article shows you how to render an icosahedron which with [flat shading](http://poniesandlight.co.uk/notes/flat_shading_on_osx/) (and optionally perhaps basic subdivision) can look like a diamond

[image: ofVbo]

The point is you need to get used to working with vbos, vertices and faces.
Once you've got the hang of that you can explore geometry

You can work out the indices to draw a common diamond (using the polar to cartesian formula and a bit of offsetting/scaling):

[image: diamond]

Or you can explore geometry further by looking at:

- platonic solids (see icosahedron/dodecahedron)
- archimidean solids
- polar zonohedron maybe ? (I played with this a bit in [Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398570/problems-rendering-a-polar-zonohedron-in-processing) porting [Rob Bell](http://zomadic.com)'s Polar Zonohedron free Sketchup Ruby Script, plenty of interesting geometry on his site)

If you have the time also explore resources from geometers like [Paul Bourke](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/) or [George Hart](http://georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/vp.html)